# Hudson not building projects when SVN post-commit trigger received

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, build-triggers

I am trying to set up Hudson continuous integration server so that any SVN commits will trigger a new build. I've seen lots of questions and answers on stackoverflow regarding configuring the SVN server, but not much on configuring Hudson.

I have added a post-commit hook to the SVN server which will contact Hudson on a commit. I am using the post-commit hook as described here: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Plugin

But a build is not triggered after an SVN commit. I got the UUID value from the above post-commit hook script and sent my own HTTP POST request to the Hudson server:

```
http://<server>/hudson/subversion/<uuid>/notifyCommit?rev=<rev>
```

The Hudson logs show the following after that:

```
WARNING: No subversion jobs using SCM polling
```

So my HTTP POST request is reaching Hudson, but Hudson is complaining that there's no jobs configured to do anything with this notification.

According to the link above, I need to (a) set up SCM polling (any schedule is sufficient) and (b) allow anonymous read access and (c) disable cross-site exploit checks.

So I configured one of my Hudson jobs to use SCM polling for a nightly build, and verified that cross-site exploit checking was disabled. I also have "Enable security" option disabled, implying (I assume) that anonymous read access is permitted.

I then again sent the HTTP POST request representing an SVN commit notification. This time there is no message in the system logs, implying no warning of jobs without SCM polling. But there is still no build.

It seems to me that Hudson can recognize a build trigger via a HTTP POST request, and knows there is a job with SCM polling that can accept the build trigger, but fails to trigger a build.

I'm wondering what I need to do to fix this. Do I need to enable security and explicitly allow anonymous read access? Or enable the "anyone can do anything" authorization option? Do I need to change the SCM polling in some way (currently set to "0 2 * * *") ?

Any help appreciated.

**edit**: I am running Hudson within Tomcat, and Tomcat is started as a service on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Before v3.0.0 (v2.2.1 and earlier), the polling feature in Hudson has two meanings:

1) If you select polling and put in a schedule, that job will run, looking for any changes at the designated times.  This job will ignore any post-commit hooks from your SCM, just like build jobs that have no polling at all

2) Enable polling but leave the actual polling field **blank**.  This allows Hudson to "passively" poll:  ie, it sits idly until a post-commit trigger comes to Hudson, and only at that time will the build jobs run.

My recommendation is to enable polling as you did, but take the schedule out.  Let the community know if this resolves your issue.